# Program that can apply calibration frames to individual subs - Astrophotography

Tags: astrophotography

With Deepskystacker or similar programs it's easy to add calibration frames which are applied to the final output image after stacking all your subs, however I would like to apply them to each sub to make a video with. Is there a program that can do this (or ideally is there an option in DeepSkyStacker to do this)?

Answer (score 1):

If anyone else ever has this issue I figured out DeepSkyStacker can do it. Go to Options->Settings->Intermediate Files and check

```
Create a calibrated file for each light frame
Save a debayered image when processing RAW images
Create a registered/calibrated file for each light frame
```

I'm unsure which of these options is the one that is needed (I just checked all of them), but if all are checked it will output calibrated subs.